# MCARI vegetation index in ArcGIS raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator, vegetation-index

I'm trying to write the equation for the MCARI vegetation index in raster calculator using WorldView-2 imagery, but can't get it right. Here is the original formula:

```
MCARI = [(RedEdge – Red) – 0.2 × (RedEdge - Green)] × (RedEdge ÷ Red)
```

Here is where I'm at:

```
[float((B6-B5)-0.2) * float(B6-B3)] * float(B6)/(B5)
```

The error I get is:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number (error 000539)
```

I'm thinking my float placement or parens placement is not correct.

Comment: `Float()` may be case sensitive.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo while writing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`float()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) is a python builtin. You can only pass strings or numbers to it.

What you need is [`Float()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/float.htm) which is from the `arcpy.sa` package (which is already imported when using the raster calculator, you only need to import it if writing python scripts).

Something like:

```
(Float(B6)-B5-0.2) * (Float(B6)-B3) * Float(B6)/B5
```

Note how I've only put `Float` around single bands - that's because you can run into [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) and truncation issues using `Float(B6-B5)` as the floating point conversion isn't done until *after* the subtraction. This is more of a best practice thing, some software will handle the type conversion implicitly and you never need to think about it, but others won't, for example in numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a=np.ones(1, dtype=np.uint8)

>>> a
array([1], dtype=uint8)

>>> float(a - 2)  # should == -1.0 right...?
255.0             # nope...
```